# LibreOffice creates lock file

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, 20.04, libreoffice, lock

I'm unable to access libreoffice files in Ubuntu.It's creating lock files and not opening. Why is it happening? Please tell the solution.

Comment: Close your libreoffice properly. You then will not have lock files next time you open the file.

Answer (score 1):

Some software locks files when they are being edited so that they cannot be simultaneously edited by another program or another user.

If you do not close the file or otherwise shut down the software properly, the file can remain locked.  Make sure that you properly exit your software and/or close the files you are working with before exiting LibreOffice.